# How to prevent flushing data in test database after every test case in Django

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I am currently writing my first Django application and writing selenium test cases for testing the UI.
I am using the Django test case class for testing the app.
This is the configuration for running test cases:

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "test",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\manage.py",
            "args": [
                "test",
                "review.tests.test_selenium.ReviewTests.test_app",
                "--keepdb"
            ],
            "django": true
        }
]
```

This configuration uses the existing test database and I have to add data in the tables each time I run a new test case.
Is there any way to preserve data after running test-cases?

Answer (score 1):

For testing, data is not stored separately. For this there is
`setUp` function. Or use the `--keepdb` flag.

Comment: There are no other options.